# Java deadlocking example in Well-grounded java developer

Tags: java, concurrency

I didn't understand the deadlocking example in the book of "Well-grounded java developer". How could this deadlock?

> At first glance, this code looks sensible. You have two updates being sent to separate threads, each of which has to be confirmed on backup threads. This doesn’t seem too outlandish a design—if one thread has a failure, there is another thread that can potentially carry on.
>   If you run the code, you’ll normally see an example of a deadlock—both threads will report receiving the update, but neither will confirm receiving the update for which they’re the backup thread. The reason for this is that each thread requires the other to release the lock it holds before the confirmation method can progress.

Below is from Listing 4.2 A deadlocking example

```
public class MicroBlogNode implements SimpleMicroBlogNode {
private final String ident;

public MicroBlogNode(String ident_) {
    ident = ident_;
}

public String getIdent() {
    return ident;
}

public synchronized void propagateUpdate(Update upd_, MicroBlogNode
        backup_) {
    System.out.println(ident + ": recvd: " + upd_.getUpdateText()  + " ; backup: " + backup_.getIdent());
    backup_.confirmUpdate(this, upd_);
}

public synchronized void confirmUpdate(MicroBlogNode other_, Update
        update_) {
    System.out.println(ident + ": recvd confirm: " + update_.getUpdateText() + " from " + other_.getIdent()k);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final MicroBlogNode local = new MicroBlogNode("localhost:8888");
    final MicroBlogNode other = new MicroBlogNode("localhost:8988");
    final Update first = getUpdate("1");
    final Update second = getUpdate("2");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            local.propagateUpdate(first, other);
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            other.propagateUpdate(second, local);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thread starts, `local.propagateUpdate` is called and `local` is now locked because the method is synchronized.

Almost simultaneously, the second thread is started, `other.propagateUpdate` is called and the instance `other` is also locked for the same reason.

Both threads happily print the text. In the first thread, the `local` instance tries to confirm with the other thread by calling `confirmUpdate` on the `other` instance, but `other` is still locked by the second thread - that method hasn't returned yet.

In the second thread, the `other` instance tries to call `confirmUpdate` on the `local` instance, but that instance is also locked - this time by the first thread.

`local` and `other` are both waiting on each other to release their locks, and will never be able to resolve the issue: this is deadlock.

Comment: Also, a deadlock isn't guaranteed because there is a _race condition_: if the first thread is able to call `confirmUpdate()` before the second thread calls `propagateUpdate()`, the code runs fine.